# Charging cell interfering with voltage measurement - how to solve?

Tags: batteries, charging

So I have a MDBT42Q connected to a LFP cell as power supply.
Its voltage is 3.32v or lower, working perfectly.

I have programmed the MDBT42Q to advertise (BLE) its name every few seconds. It also checks the battery voltage every 10 minutes and advertises this as well. Working great so far.

Now I have connected a charging circuit which has 5v input (I use USB-C) and outputs 3.65v for charging the LFP cell. It is connected parallel to the battery which is connected to the BLE chip. This works well, I can charge the battery without turning the BLE off.

Problem is: after I have connected the charger (USB not plugged!), the voltage measurement is not working properly anymore. The charging circuit (chinese TP5000) seems to "measure" battery voltage even when it has no power input itself. The voltage measurement of the BLE jumps up and down, unable to get a reasonable SOC.

Either the TP5000 is faulty (I don't think so) or it simply is built this way. My idea was to cut it from the battery when USB is not connected, but how to?
Any hint is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the voltage measurement part and the TP5000 to get useful answers.

Comment: I have added two pictures of TP5000. what do you mean with "voltage measurement part"? I use firmware / software of MDBT42Q to do this. have you read my full post?

Comment: OK, and how do you use the ADC of the BLE Module? Any voltage divider resistors, filter capacitors?

Comment: I don't think so, the software just calls the appropriate function to measure. Interesting effect: when I measure a few times right after another, the value lowers. Until I wait a couple of seconds. Looks like a capacitor - maybe one of them in the schematics. So I believe it would be useful, to cut connection from BLE to charger when no USB is connected. Any idea?

Comment: Disconnecting the charger could be a kind of workaround, but I would try to understand how and what exactly the hardware of the BLE module measures. It is much better to fix the problem there, or it will come back later when you connect other additional loads to the battery.

Comment: Just found in the docs of the firmware: "Note: This value is calculated by reading the voltage on an internal voltage reference with the ADC."

Comment: Which of the 4 pins, that can measure analog values, do you use and how is this pin connected to the battery? A direct connection can destroy the ADC input.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know wich pins are used since I am just calling a firmware function. And I am actually using a E73-2G4M08S1C (nRF52840) instead of the MDBT42Q, but is very similar. It is powered via pin 19 (+) and pin 5 (-). (Link to datasheet: https://www.ebyte.com/en/downpdf.aspx?id=445).